# Spring. REST запросом

Tags: ajax, spring

Доброго времени суток.

Изучаю Spring и столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть REST контроллер. К которому направляется AJAX -запрос с страницы с параметром имя пользователя. В ответ он отдает из сервиса данные. 
Контроллер

```
@RestController

public class SearchController {

    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/search")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getSearchResultViaAjax(
            @Valid @RequestBody SearchCriteria search, Errors errors) {

        ResponseObjects result = new ResponseObjects();


        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            result.setMsg("err");
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(result);
        }

        User users = userService.findByUserNameOrEmail(search.getUsername());
        if (users==null) {
            result.setMsg("no user found!");
        } else {
            result.setMsg("success");
        }

        result.setResult(users);


        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);

    }
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public String getResp(){
        return "greeting";
    }


}
```

Сервис

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService{
    public UserService(UserRepo userRepo) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo; // вместо Autowired
    }
    private List<User> users;
    private final UserRepo userRepo;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    }
    public User findByUserNameOrEmail(String username) {
       return userRepo.findByUsername(username);

    }


}
```

AJAX

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


        $("#search-form").submit(function (event) {

            //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
            event.preventDefault();

            fire_ajax_submit();

        });

    });

    function fire_ajax_submit() {

        var search = {}
        search["username"] = $("#uname").val();

        $("#btn-search").prop("disabled", true);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/search",
            data: JSON.stringify(search),
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (data) {
                var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"
                    + JSON.stringify(data, null, 1) + "</pre>";
                $('#feedback').html(json);

                console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
                $("#btn-search").prop("disabled", false);

            },
            error: function (e) {

                var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"
                    + e.responseText +"</pre>";
                $('#feedback').html(json);

                console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                $("#btn-search").prop("disabled", false);

            }
        });

    }
```

WebSecurituConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()  // включаем авторизацию на главной страницк
                    .antMatchers("/","/search","/registration","/activate/*") // полный доступ
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth
               .userDetailsService(userService)
               .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());

    }

}
```

В Chrome:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На что обратить внимание? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: До отправки ajax запроса, уже авторизовались?

Comment: Да. авторизацию прошел. GET запросы проходят.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос значения заголовков у этого запроса, включая cookie.

Comment: Проблема решена. По неопытности или глупости забыл про csrf.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. По неопытности или глупости забыл про csrf
Thymeleaf:

```html
<meta id="_csrf" name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}" />
<meta id="_csrf_header" name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}" />
```

AJAX:

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

$(document).ready(function () {


    $("#search-form").submit(function (event) {

        //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
        event.preventDefault();
        fire_ajax_submit();

    });

});


function fire_ajax_submit() {

    var search = {}
    search["username"] = $("#uname").val();

    $("#btn-search").prop("disabled", true);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/search",
        data: JSON.stringify(search),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"
                + JSON.stringify(data, null, 1) + "</pre>";
            $('#feedback').html(json);

            console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
            $("#btn-search").prop("disabled", false);

        },
        error: function (e) {

            var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"
                + e.responseText +"</pre>";
            $('#feedback').html(json);

            console.log("ERROR : ", e);
            $("#btn-search").prop("disabled", false);

        }
    });

}
```